# Makefile uses files in different directories conditionally

Tags: c, makefile

I have two versions of code for project A, and project A is written based on project B. I need to modify a Makefile to compile project A based on versions of project B. For example:

| Project B version | Project A version | Path to Project A code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 3.0 | ~/tmp/a3 |
| 2.0 | 4.0 | ~/tmp/a4 |
| 3.0 | 6.0 | ~/tmp/a6 |

And I have version of project B in an environment variable.

```
> echo $VERSION_B
> 1.0
```

The file directory layout:

```
> tree /tmp
> .
├── a3
│   ├── a3.c
│   ├── a3.o
├── a4
│   ├── a4.c
│   ├── a4.o
├── a6
│   ├── a6.c
│   ├── a6.o
├── helper.c
├── helper.o
└── Makefile
```

The Makefile looks like:

```
MODULE_big = A

OBJS = a3.o a3.o helper.o
...
```

Looks like I need to change OBJS based on `$VERSION_B`. I thought I can do something like:

```
MODULE_big = A

all: 
    ifeq ("1.0", $(VERSION_B))
        OBJS = a3/a3.c a3/a3.o helper.o
    else
        ifeq ("2.0",  $(VERSION_B))
            OBJS = a4/a4.c a4/a4.o helper.o
        else
            OBJS = a6/a6.c a6/a6.o helper.o
```

But it doesn't work.
Is it possible to choose the file path of project A based on project B version in Makefile?

Comment: I assume you have indented all those lines with TAB characters.  That cannot work, because lines indented with TAB characters are sent to the shell as shell commands, and these are make operations.

Comment: It's odd that you're including what appear to be source file names (e.g. a4/a4.c) in the value of a variable named `OBJS`, which I would expect to designate object files.  But that's not directly relevant to the question posed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [constructed macro names](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/), like this:

```
OBJS_1.0 = a3/a3.c a3/a3.o helper.o
OBJS_2.0 = a4/a4.c a4/a4.o helper.o
OBJS_3.0 = a6/a6.c a6/a6.o helper.o

OBJS := $(OBJS_$(VERSION_B))
```